# Inserting an event in an array of events with specific rules

Tags: javascript, algorithm, momentjs

I have a list of events on a given day. (events time is a moment object)

```
[
  { id: 1, start: '2017-05-01 05:00'},
  { id: 2, start: '2017-05-01 08:00'},
  { id: 3, start: '2017-05-01 14:00'},
  { id: 4, start: '2017-05-01 17:00'}
]
```

I need to add one event in this array so that the new event time is not less than 5am, is at least 3 hours after the previous event (if there is one) and 3h before the next event (if there is one). The new event should be planned on the same day.

In this case, it would insert the new event just after id = 2 and at 11am.

I started something but it ended up with a dozen of *ifs* and I got lost after a few hours thinking:

```
    // for each event, check if there's time before or after (not less than 5am, not more than 11:59pm)
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var eventTime = events[i].start.clone();
        var before = eventTime.clone();
        var after = eventTime.clone();
        before.subtract('hours', 3);
        after.add('hours', 3);
        if(i == 0 && !before.hour() < 5 && !before.isBefore(date, 'day')) {
            // first event of the day, new time cannot be before 5am and cannot be on the previous day
            hour = before.hour();
        } else if(i == 0 && !after.isAfter(date, 'day')) {
            // same as above but we test time + 3h
        } else if(i == events.length - 1 && !after.isAfter(date, 'day')) {
            // last event of the day, new time cannot be the next day (after 11:59pm)
            hour = after.hour();
        } else if (i > 0 && i < events.length - 1) {
            // middle events
            // new time should be at least 3H after previous event and 3H before next event
            // ex: 5h, 8h, 12h ok but 5h, 8h, 10h not ok or 5h, 6h, 9h not ok
            var previousEventTime = events[i-1].start.clone();
            var nextEventTime = events[i+1].start.clone();
            if(before.hour() >= previousEventTime.hour() && after.hour() <= nextEventTime.hour()) {

            }
            //
        }
    }
```

Here is a snippet that can be used:

```js
var events = [
  { id: 1, start: 'Mon, 01 May 2017 05:00:00 +0200'},
  { id: 2, start: 'Mon, 01 May 2017 08:00:00 +0200'},
  { id: 3, start: 'Mon, 01 May 2017 14:00:00 +0200'},
  { id: 4, start: 'Mon, 01 May 2017 17:00:00 +0200'}
];

 for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var eventTime = moment(events[i].start).clone();
      var before = moment(eventTime).clone();
      var after = moment(eventTime).clone();
      before.subtract(3, 'hours');
      after.add(3, 'hours');
      console.log(eventTime, before, after);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What should be the output ?

Comment: It could be an integer representing the time of the day the event can be inserted. (11 in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a day on this I came up with a "mathematical" solution.

In my array I want to insert an event ***y*** between an event ***x*** and an event ***z***. (x being the previous event and z the next one)

Since I need 3 hours minimum between each event I figured:

```
x+3 <= y-3 || y+3 <= z-3
```

The one I implemented is a little bit different. I figured I needed at least 6 hours between 2 events to be able to insert a new event in the middle.

```
y-x > =6 || z-y >= 6
```

Since my brain is not far from burning out the code looks like this...

```
        for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var x = null;
            var y = events[i].start.clone().hour();
            var z = null;
            if(i > 0) {
                x = events[i-1].start.clone().hour();
            }
            if(i < events.length -1) {
                z = events[i+1].start.clone().hour();
            }
            // first event or only event
            if(i == 0) {
                // check if removing 3h00 doesn't cross the 5am limit
                if(y - 3 >= 5) {
                    hour = y - 3;
                } else if(z-y >= 6) {
                    // check if there's enough time before next event
                    hour = y + 3;
                }
            }
            // middle event
            if(x && z) {
                if (y-x >= 6) {
                    hour = y - 3;
                } else if (z-y >= 6) {
                    hour = y + 3;
                }
            }
            // last event (can also be first if only 1 element)
            // with !hour we make sure that a "middle" event hour is not overriden if found above
            if(!hour && i == events.length - 1 && i != 0) {
                // check if adding 3h00 doesn't change day (23h00)
                if(y + 3 <= 23) {
                    hour = y + 3;
                } else if(y-x >= 6) {
                    // check if there's enough time after previous event
                    hour = y - 3;
                }
            }
        }
        return hour;
```

I'd be glad to accept an answer that improves on this algorithm.